# Jenkins pipeline unit testing: load scripts from different repos

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

My team would like to start unit testing our Jenkins pipeline code as it is something we are sorely lacking and having tests for our infra is something that is going to help us massively and speed up our development changes.

I have found 2 viable options so far:

1. [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit)
2. [Jenkins-spock](https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/jenkins-spock)

These both seem like good options but they both have 1 major issue that I'd like to try and sort out before choosing one.

In both testing frameworks, there are helper methods to load a pipeline script for testing, something along the lines of `loadPipelineScriptForTest('src/<somepath>/myJenkinsfileScript.groovy')`. The problem with this is that we have 2 repositories containing groovy script code that we want to test:

1. jenkins-shared-library (with the typical directory structure described [in the docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/))
2. jenkins-scripts (this repo stores ALL our Jenkinsfile scripts. The reason for doing this was to reduce multiple copies of a Jenkinsfile into 1 script stored in 1 place, allowing us to modify the Jenkins pipelines for multiple services very easily by only needing to modify the script in 1 location)

My preference would be to have a `jenkins-testing` repo that stores ALL the unit tests for ALL of our jenkins pipeline code. This would mean I need a solution to load the groovy scripts from a completely different repository, and I'm not sure this is possible. This is the main part of my problem, I need a way to load the scripts from a different but I don't know how.

The other solution would be to store unit tests inside the repositories for the repos we already have as I described them above. This would mean that the unit tests are split up, the `jenkins-shared-library` repo will only store unit tests for shared-library functions, the `jenkins-scripts` repo will only store unit tests for our jenkins scripts.

Again, I think the ideal solution would be to store all the unit tests in a single place in a separate repository, but if this is not possible or a good idea, I understand I can store the unit tests in the respective repositories, but it means I'll have to run 2 test suites to complete the jenkins unit testing.

Comment: I haven't done it but JenkinsPipelineUnit has different ways of loading a library for testing, including from another git repo. https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit?tab=readme-ov-file#testing-pipelines-that-use-shared-libraries